# How to add an application specific service contextual menu for an automator created service

Tags: software-recommendation, automator, software, services, menu-bar

I have just created a service for my text editor. 
I would like to be able to add a services item in the text editor contextual menu when right clicking.
Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your service restrict it to your text editor while creating the service in Automator and save it to ~/Library/Services/.

Example:

[image]

After selecting some text, the context menu offers the service "fiona-babbles":

[image]